# How do I simultaneously dispatch a method to a number of instances when before it only dispatched to one?

Tags: ruby, design-patterns

In my hypothetical application, users can ask questions, which are then answered by an `Oracle`. You can use the `Predictor.predictor` method to get an appropriate `Oracle`, to whom you can then direct your questions. When you `#ask` a question, you'll get a response, along with the `Oracle`'s certainty (a floating-point number in the range 0..1) about its response.

```
class BaseOracle; def ask(question); ...; end; end
class UnreliableOracle < BaseOracle; ...; end

module Predictor
  def self.predictor
    @predictor ||= UnreliableOracle.new
  end
end

Predictor.predictor.ask("How many fingers am I holding up?")
 # => ["three fingers", 0.2]
```

In this implementation, you get the same Oracle every time, an UnreliableOracle instance. What I would like to do is to change the implementation of Predictor.predictor so that methods which are invoked on it are delegated to a *collection* of Oracles, some of which are better than others. In other words, I want it to work something like this:

```
class BaseOracle; ...; end
class UnreliableOracle < BaseOracle; ...; end
class PopCultureOracle < BaseOracle; ...; end
class ScienceOracle < BaseOracle; ...; end
class LiteraryOracle < BaseOracle; ...; end
class FingerCountingOracle < BaseOracle; ...; end

module Predictor
  def self.predictor
    ############## What goes here?
  end
end

# This actually asks several oracles for an answer and picks the best one.
Predictor.predictor.ask("How many fingers am I holding up?")
 # => ["four fingers", 1.0]
```

What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially the **[strategy design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)**, where each Oracle is effectively a strategy for answering questions.

The easiest (and perhaps cleanest) approach is to construct a `MetaOracle` that asks the other oracles what the right answer is and picks the best answer:

```
class MetaOracle
  def oracles
    @oracles ||= [ScienceOracle.new, LiteraryOracle.new, # ...
  end

  def ask(question)
    oracles.map { |o| o.ask question }.        # Ask each Oracle a question ...
      sort_by { |answer| -answer.certainty }.  # sort by the best answers ...
      first                                    # ... and pick the best one.
  end
end

module Predictor
  def self.predictor
    @predictor ||= MetaOracle.new
  end
end
```

Now the Oracle with the best answer wins and will be the answer that you see.